# How to get just the value from a Sql statement instead of column name

Tags: sql, groovy

How can i retrieve just the value in my output instead of a columnName: value,
Below i have attached my Sql statement. It retrieves the value with the column name.

```
sql.eachRow('select top 5 * from [MACHINES] WHERE Total != Right order by Time')
{ row ->
    logger.info  "$row"
}
```

The output i receive is Machinename: A12. How can i print just A12 and omit Machinename. Thank you in advance!

Comment: `logger.info(  row.Machinename )`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like below.

```
logger.info "$row.Machinename"
```

OR

```
String expectedOutput = "$row".split(":")[1]
logger.info expectedOutput
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. But what if if have  Machinename: A12, ProgramName:asdwsd, MachineName2: A13, ......... I got for the above code output as:  A12, ProgramName. how can i use the split for this kind of output